# Refresh Master-Detail gridcontrol

Tags: devexpress, entity

I have a devexpress Master-View gridcontrol , bound to Entity bindingsource.
Programatically I update some records on bindingsource , but the Gridcontrol is not refreshed with new data.
I use the following methods : ( GridviewMaster - is Master View , GridviewChild  - is Detail view )

```
      GridControl1.RefreshDataSource()
      GridControl1.MainView.RefreshData()
      GridControl1.DefaultView.RefreshData()
      GridViewMaster.RefreshData()
      GridViewChild.RefreshData()
```

But without success.I know that the bindingsource is updated , but the Gridcontrol is not. Only when i close and open the form again the gridcontrol is updated.
What can I do ? ( without querying again the database)
Thank you !
        '

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried rebinding it to the datasource?

```
GridViewMaster.DataSource = DataSource;
GridViewMaster.DataBind();
```

This reloads the table with the new data.

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled upon the same problem and the only way I came up with to force refresh the affected rows was to collapse and reexpand them (if they are expanded in the first place - collapsed rows don't need this sort of thing):

```
        var rowsWhichNeedToBeRefreshed = ...; // find the master rows which are expanded using e.g. GetMasterRowExpanded()
        if (rowsWhichNeedToBeRefreshed.Any())
        {
            try
            {
                gridcontrol.SuspendLayout();
                rowsWhichNeedToBeRefreshed.ForEach(x =>
                {
                    gridview.CollapseMasterRow(x.Item1);
                    gridview.SetMasterRowExpanded(x.Item1, 0, expand: true);
                });
            }
            finally
            {
                gridcontrol.ResumeLayout(performLayout: true);
            }
        }
```